# F# type constraints indexable

Tags: indexing, f#, type-constraints

I'm trying to make a type that should represent a "slice" of some indexable collection.

I know that there are some similar types in F# but not one that specifies the criteria that I need.

To do this it needs to carry a reference to the collection of type 'content and the content needs to be indexable. So I tried this constraint since a type only needs to have the member Item (get/set) so I tried this

```
type Slice<'a, 'content when 'content: (member Item: int -> 'a)>
```

This still throw the usual error

So is it possible to constrain a type to still be generic but constraint to be indexable?

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```ml
type Slice<'a, 'content when 'content: (member get_Item: int -> 'a)> =
    {
        Content : 'content
        Start : int
        Stop : int
    }
    with
    member inline slice.get_Item(i) =
        slice.Content.get_Item(slice.Start + i)
```

I've implemented `get_Item` on `Slice` as well, so you can take a slice of a slice. Here are some values of this type:

```ml
let strSlice =
    {
        Content = "hello"
        Start = 1
        Stop = 2
    }

let arraySlice =
    {
        Content = [| 2; 4; 6; 8 |]
        Start = 0
        Stop = 3
    }

let strSliceSlice =
    {
        Content = strSlice
        Start = 0
        Stop = 1
    }
```

Comment: then comes the next problem, if I'm trying to make my slice indexable too it complains that 'a escapes the scope.

Comment: my question was about type constraints only

Comment: Try an `inline` member. It's a bit funky, but I think it works. See my updated answer.

Comment: VS still complains running F# v7.0.0

Comment: Are you sure? It compiles and runs successfully for me on the latest version of Visual Studio (v. 17.4.3) with F# 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
[<Interface>]
type Indexable<'a> =
    abstract member Item: int -> 'a with get

[<Struct>]
type Slice<'a> =
    {
       content: Indexable<'a>
       start: int
       len: int
    }
with
    interface Indexable<'a> with
        member I.Item with get(i) = I.[idx]

    member S.Item with get(idx) = 
         if idx >= S.len 
         then raise(IndexOutOfRangeException()) 
         else S.content.[S.start+idx]
```

This works.

Comment: OK, but using an interface means you can't index built-in types, like `string`.

Comment: not easily no, but that is what anonymise objects are for.